# why in redirecting url changes in the console but not in the browser (django)?

Tags: django

When redirecting the url in the console changes but not in the browser

view.py

```
def tables(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        text = request.POST.get('data_table')
        table_to_file(text)
        return redirect(reverse('result'))
    else:
        matrix = Matrix.objects.all()
        context = {'matrix': matrix}
        return render(request, 'methods/tables.html', context)

def result(request):
    return render(request, 'methods/result.html')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns =[
    path('result/', result, name = 'result'),
    path('tables/', tables, name='tables'),
```

In console

```
[20/Jun/2022 00:22:17] "POST /methods/tables/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[20/Jun/2022 00:22:17] "GET /methods/result/ HTTP/1.1" 200 571
```

But nothing changes in the browser

Answer (score 0):

Your POST is hitting the if statement in tables() and returning results, your GET is being directed to result() which is also returning results, your GET is not going to tables(), so your else statement is never being hit